404 Errors in Nginx Reverse Proxy for Odoo on Google Cloud
Encountering perplexing intermittent 404 errors with Nginx reverse proxy setup for Odoo on Google Cloud. Initially functional, the setup starts exhibiting errors after a brief period. Here's a details:
Observations and Issues:
Intermittent 404 Errors: The system initially operates smoothly but starts returning intermittent 404 errors after a short duration.
Empty Error Log: Notably, the error.log remains empty during instances of 404 errors, hindering diagnostic efforts.
Temporary Fix via Cache Clearing: Clearing the cache in Chrome temporarily resolves the issue, suggesting a potential caching-related complication.
Setup Overview:
Domain Name: Utilizing a domain name (my_domain_name.com) procured from Namecheap, configured to point to the IP address of the Google Cloud instance.
Nginx Configuration: Below is the Nginx configuration file:
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odootchat {
server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domaine_name.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
          proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odootchat;
        }
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}

The 404 error
I tried checking the Nginx error log (error.log) for any clues, but surprisingly, it remained empty during instances of the errors. I expected to find error messages or logs that could provide insight into the cause of the 404 errors. However, despite clearing the cache in Chrome, the issue persisted intermittently, disrupting the smooth functioning of the setup.
